# Can I assign a value to a conditional expression in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, ternary-operator, assignment-operator, conditional-operator

Is it valid to simplify this...

```c++
if (bool_b) {
    int_i1 = int_i3;
} else {
    int_i2 = int_i3;
}
```

..into the following?

```c++
(bool_b ? int_i1 : int_i2) = int_i3;
```

It seems to work on my compiler. But I think the [draft C++11 standard: N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) says it's invalid:

> - conditional-expression:
>
>   - logical-or-expression
>   - logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
> - assignment-expression:
>
>   - conditional-expression
>   - logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
>   - throw-expression

If I understand it well, the part at the left of `=` should be a *logical-or-expression*. But even though *logical-or-expression* are *conditional-expression*s, the reciprocal is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's valid if the two alternatives of the ternary operator are both lvalues of the same type.

> **N3242 5.16/4** : If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that
>   type and value category

The ternary operator is called conditional operator.

**Gramar aspects:**

The following gramar production :

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

allow statements like:

```
true ? b : a = 20;      // yields b. if condition would be false, would yield a =20
true ? b = 11 : a = 21; // yields b=11
```

As the gramar shows well the assignement would be limited to one of the branch

However, if we consider the full chain of gramar productions:

```
assignment-expression: 
    logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
    ...
logical-or-expression:
    logical-and-expression
    logical-or-expression || logical-and-expression
logical-and-expression:
    inclusive-or-expression
    logical-and-expression && inclusive-or-expression
...  
primary-expression: 
    (expression) 
    ...
```

So you could then write expressions like :

```
(true ? a : b) = 10;    // a and b are lvalues,  a or be are set to 10 depending on the condition
```

Comment: Lvalues? You mean I can't do `int i = f ? 3 : 4`, since integer literals are prvalues?

Comment: @legends2k "If", not "only if".  Ternary operator takes all value categories for the second and third expressions.

Comment: @legends2k I was refering to the question: `(bool_b ? int_i1 : int_i2) = int_i3;` is valid if both  `int_i1 and `int_i2` are lvalues.   It's not valid if you mix with literals:  `(bool_b ? int_i1 : 10) = int_i3;` is invalid, as the conditional cannot ensure returning an lvalue for the assignement.

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses are important partly because of the language detail you noticed.  `bool_b ? int_i1 : int_i2` is not a *logical-or-expression*, but `(bool_b ? int_i1 : int_i2)` is a *primary-expression* and therefore also a *logical-or-expression*.

Comment: Oh, I didn't consider the parentheses. Thanks.